# Android scaling/transforming canvas doesn't modify clickable area

Tags: java, android, canvas

I'm having a very similar issue [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808234/android-scaleanimation-doesnt-scale-clickable-area), except instead of using ScaleAnimation, I'm allowing pinch zoom/pan in my RelativeLayout.

The zoom/panning works perfectly, but regardless of how my view is panned/zoomed, the clickable area does not change along with the visual representation. Here's what my dispatchTouchEvent looks like:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (mScaleGestureDetector != null && mGestureDetector != null) {
        mScaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    final int action = ev.getAction();
    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            final float x = ev.getX();
            final float y = ev.getY();

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;
            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
            final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
            final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

            // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
            if (!mScaleGestureDetector.isInProgress() && mScaleFactor > 1f) {
                final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                float newPosX = mPosX + dx;
                float newPosY = mPosY + dy;
                if (isCoordinateInBound(newPosX, mScreenSize.x))
                    mPosX = newPosX;
                if (isCoordinateInBound(newPosY, mScreenSize.y))
                    mPosY = newPosY;

                invalidate();
            }

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;

            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
            final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK)
                    >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
            final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
            if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

and my dispatchDraw:

```
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
    canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);

    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

How do you modify the clickable area accordingly to modified scale/transformation of canvas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are already onverriding `dispatchTouchEvent`, you can try this:

1. manually evaluate each `MotionEvent` by considering the current zoom/pan transformation; you can create a **new** `MotionEvent` (let's call it *FakeMotionEvent*) by applying the **reverse zoom/pan transformation** to the original `MotionEvent` **m**.
2. Check if the *FakeMotionEvent* **intercepts** a specific `View` **v**; this means the user is touching in a position which represents the user-visibile position of **v**.
3. If *FakeMotionEvent* intercepts **v**, consume the current `MotionEvent` and invoke `v.dispatchTouchEvent(m);`

**TIP**: You can use the method below to evaluate if a `MotionEvent` intercepts a `View` with a certain degree of tolerance:

```
private boolean intercept(MotionEvent ev, View view, float boundingBoxTolerance){
    if (boundingBoxTolerance < 1.0f) {
        boundingBoxTolerance = 1.0f;
    }
    try {
        if (ev != null && view != null) {
            int coords[] = new int[2];
            view.getLocationOnScreen(coords);
            if (ev.getRawX() >= ((float)coords[0]) / boundingBoxTolerance && ev.getRawX() <= coords[0] + ((float) view.getWidth()) * boundingBoxTolerance) {
                if(ev.getRawY() >= ((float)coords[1]) / boundingBoxTolerance && ev.getRawY() <= coords[1] + ((float) view.getHeight()) * boundingBoxTolerance)
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
    return false;
}
```

Comment: With this solution, would this mean that I'd need to check for every interactable views on my layout (Button, edittext, etc)? That seems rather inefficient.

Comment: @l46kok Yes I know. It's the price to pay if you want to handle the dispatching of touch events manually :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using [View Animations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html), i will prefer to use [Property animations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) instead

excerpt from Android documentation (see highlighted)

> The view animation system provides the capability to only animate View
>   objects, so if you wanted to animate non-View objects, you have to
>   implement your own code to do so. The view animation system is also
>   constrained in the fact that it only exposes a few aspects of a View
>   object to animate, such as the scaling and rotation of a View but not
>   the background color, for instance.
>
> **Another disadvantage of the view animation system is that it only
>   modified where the View was drawn, and not the actual View itself. For
>   instance, if you animated a button to move across the screen, the
>   button draws correctly, but the actual location where you can click
>   the button does not change, so you have to implement your own logic to
>   handle this.**
>
> With the property animation system, these constraints are completely
>   removed, and you can animate any property of any object (Views and
>   non-Views) and the object itself is actually modified. The property
>   animation system is also more robust in the way it carries out
>   animation. At a high level, you assign animators to the properties
>   that you want to animate, such as color, position, or size and can
>   define aspects of the animation such as interpolation and
>   synchronization of multiple animators.
>
> The view animation system, however, takes less time to setup and
>   requires less code to write. If view animation accomplishes everything
>   that you need to do, or if your existing code already works the way
>   you want, there is no need to use the property animation system. It
>   also might make sense to use both animation systems for different
>   situations if the use case arises.